# Youtube V3 List API is returning blank items, when video uploading is failed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube v3 PHP API to upload videos on youtube. After uploading I check the status of uploaded video using list API. The list API used to give the video in items array in response irrespective of whatever video upload/processing status maybe. But before 4 days, it suddenly stopped sending video info if video upload gets failed for any reason like duplicate upload. How should I fix this?

```
public static function uploadVideo_($file, $filename, $target_dir, $params = []){
        try {
            if (is_array($file)) {
                $ret = self::uploadToLocalFromArray_($file, $filename, $target_dir);
            } else {
                $ret = self::uploadToLocal_($file, $filename, $target_dir);
            }
            if(!$ret){
                throw Exception("Failed to upload video on local");
            }
            $client = Yii::$app->google->getService();
            $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        $videoPath = $target_dir.$filename;

        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle(@$params['title']);
        $snippet->setDescription(@$params['description']);
        $snippet->setTags(@$params['tags']);
        $snippet->setCategoryId(@$params['category_id']);

        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
        // "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = "public";

        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);
        $videoId = $status['id'];
        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        // Get Video uploaded or not - alternate
        $client->setDefer(false);

        while(true){
            sleep(1);
            # Call the videos.list method to retrieve processingDetails for each video.
            $videosResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('status, processingDetails', array(
                'id' => $videoId,
            ));
            if(empty($videosResponse['items'][0])){
                continue;
            } 
            $videoResult = $videosResponse['items'][0];
            if($videoResult['processingDetails']['processingStatus'] == "processing") {
                continue;
            }
            if($videoResult['status']['uploadStatus'] == "processed" || $videoResult['status']['uploadStatus'] == "uploaded") {
                break;
            } else if($videoResult['status']['uploadStatus'] == "deleted") {
                throw new Exception("Video has been deleted.");
            } else if($videoResult['status']['uploadStatus'] == "failed") {
                throw new Exception("Video upload failed: ".$videoResult['status']['failureReason']);
            } else if($videoResult['status']['uploadStatus'] == "rejected") {
                throw new Exception("Video Rejected: ".$videoResult['status']['rejectionReason']);
            }
            /*
            if($videoResult['processingDetails']['processingStatus'] == "failed") {
                throw new Exception("");
            } else if($videoResult['processingDetails']['processingStatus'] == "succeeded") {
                break;
            } else if($videoResult['processingDetails']['processingStatus'] == "terminated") {
                return ['status'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()];
            }*/
            $client->setDefer(false);
        }

        unlink($videoPath);
        $thumb_high = $status->getSnippet()->getThumbnails()->getHigh();
        $thumb_url = str_replace("hq", "sd", $thumb_high->getUrl());
        try {
            $dim = getimagesize($thumb_url);
            $thumb_width = $dim[0];
            $thumb_height = $dim[1];
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $thumb_url = $thumb_high->getUrl();
            $thumb_width = $thumb_high->getWidth();
            $thumb_height = $thumb_high->getHeight();
        }
        return ['status'=>true, 'videoId'=>$videoId, 'thumbnail'=>$thumb_url, 'width'=>$thumb_width, 'height'=>$thumb_height];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return ['status'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()];
    }
    return ['status'=>false, 'message'=>'Unknown Reason'];
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: Happens to me too, it was working and now does not return the items. I am using the android lib.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing. I have filed a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129270261